# How to simplify design and remove duplication in java layered architecture?

Tags: java, model, http-request, dto, http-response

I've the following project structure (simplified):

- domain
- dto
- view

In `domain` model is kept. `dto` classes are used to pass data from `domain` to `view`. And in `view` I've a controller and a handful of *req, *res classes to pass the data via HTTP. So there are 3 classes (in model, dto and view) to express the same thing.

The problem is that I had a `SalesEntry` and `PurchaseEntry` in the model. Both classes where exactly the same so I had two entities but only one `EntryDto` along with `EntryReq` and `EntryRes`. All good. Now, it turned out that I need to add some fields but, to `PurchaseEntry` only. So I added some abstraction and doubled the classes in every *layer*. This was a big cost. Where did I go wrong and how should it be done correctly?

In languages other than java I'd probably pass some maps here and there, but in java in particular I need to have a concrete class in every layer. How to simplify it?

Comment: Generally you want to encapsulate the model in a facade to be used in other parts of your program.  In other words, you don't need more than one class holding the data for every possible entity.  If you're copying and pasting code in other parts of your program to do very similar things, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I already have a facade to prevent leaking model. The facade uses `dto` objects to return the model data. But I don't want use `dto` to transport data via HTTP layer. That's the question, what am I doing wrong? ;)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you must have a dedicated class for the HTTP layer?  If you were sending back JSON, for example, your facade could simply produce that JSON to be sent representing the data without the need for another layer.

Comment: @Neil, ok now I understand where you point me - to eliminate req and res classes, yes? Facade might be also used to communicate with other facades - and it definitely should not be done via JSON files.

Comment: It is needless boilerplate if you don't require it.  Create such classes only if you have good reason to do so, and not otherwise.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it _needless_. This way I have a very clear separation at not so big cost. When it comes to using entities in view I've already been there. It's a nightmare.

Comment: "Facade might be also used to communicate with other facades" - IMO you'd have to distinguish between two use cases: 1) you have communication inside one application in which case I'd not use a facade (which basically is meant for outside communication) and 2) you have communication between multiple applications (e.g. microservices) in which case using JSON as the interchange format wouldn't be that bad a choice as you'd need some serialization anyways.